# Replace special chararcters in a 60MB file

Tags: find-and-replace, special-characters

I have a big text file. 200,000 lines. 60MB.

I would like to replace :

```
&amp; -> &
&#203; -> Ë
&#202; -> Ê
etc...
```

Any simple idea please ? (Textpad or Notepad++?)

Edit : Thanks for the ideas. I want to search and replace not only theses 2 occurences but all the special chars ( ÌÍÎÏÐetc....)

Comment: Notepad: Edit -> Replace. Find what = & Replace with = & Ë

Comment: Powershell command line `(Get-Content "file.txt").replace("&amp;", "&") | Set-Content "file.txt"`

Comment: -1  Why don't you try it with regular notepad first on a small file.  You haven't shown what you're really struggling with that makes the task you ask about here so difficult for you.  Do you already know how to replace &asdf with qwerty in a small file?   If not then find out how to do that.  Do you even know how to replace "abc" with "def", if not then figure out  that. Are you even aware of how to open notepad. How far have you got to trying to complete this problem you have?

Comment: Have a look at [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: Use [EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/).

Comment: If we're doing software recommendations, then try the free and open source [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) as it can handle opening a 60 MB file just fine. Have you tried the PowerShell command I put up top? In that command in the [`replace()`](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) function you will ensure the first argument is the string to search for and the second argument is the string to replace with having both enclosed by double quotes and separated by a comma i.e. `replace("arg1", "arg2")`. Simply, easy, done, and move onto the next one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to make the file a .html file (maybe add header and footer), open it in a web browser and copy the visible text to a new file. As seems that there are html special characters in this file.